# Connecting Huawei Comet via USB -- shows as CDFS?

Tags: external-sd, usb-connection-mode

I'm trying to install a custom ringtone to my Huawei Comet, and when I connect it to my computer via USB it shows me a drive named "Mobile Partner" that is CDFS and has 0 MB free of 6.59 MB (not the 2GB MicroSD card I have installed). Do i have to use a separate SD card adaptor to plug it into my computer? Or how do I get my phone to show me the SD card?

Comment: You probably have it in Media mode or something, onik's answer should help in that case.

Comment: @MatthewRead I'd say it's in "tethering mode", since Huawei's 3G USB Modems use a software called Mobile Partner to manage the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T-Mobile Comet Manual, p.14:

**Using the microSD Card as USB Mass Storage**

To transfer all your favorite music and pictures from your PC to your mobile phone’s microSD card, set the microSD card as USB mass storage.

1. Connect your mobile phone to your PC with the USB cable. Your PC will detect the microSD card as a removable disk.
2. Open the notification bar, and then touch USB connected.
3. Touch Turn on USB storage in the dialog box that opens to confirm that you want to transfer files. You can now transfer files from your PC to your mobile phone’s microSD card.